# Excel VBA - OpenHyperlink in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

im opening a CSV file from the internet using the =FollowHyperlink() function. However the CSV gets opened in a new workbook. Is it possible to open the .csv file in the same workbook but on a new sheet, or even better directly in the same worksheet so that i can use the data from the file.

Best, JD

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1!A1"",""CLICK HERE"")"
```

Comment: Sorry i meant the =Followhyperlink() function